# How to save SQL Update for later if the server is not reachable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Currently I am using the SQLAdapter Update command to update changes from a DataTable to a SQL database.  I want to know how to cache the changes for later if the server is not available. Is there a way to extract the SQL from the Update command and execute them later on the database?

```
sqlConn = New SqlConnection(AppConnection)
sqlConn.Open()
sqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = sqlConn
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SampleTable"

Dim objSQLBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter)

'THIS IS NOT RETURNING THE COMPLETE SQL STATEMENT
sqlAdapter.UpdateCommand = objSQLBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()   

'IF THIS FAILS, I WANT TO CACHE THE SQL AND EXECUTE THE SQL LATER...
sqlAdapter.Update(dtDataTable)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `sqlAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText` is not complete?

Comment: Correct, it does not contain all if the SQL... It creates parameters for every column, but never sets them to an value in the CommandText.   It must pass values to those parameters internally.   You can tell by comparing CommandText against SQL Profiler to see exactly what was really sent.   Profiler shows all the values being set to each parameter... CommandText s missing all the data.   Really bazaar!